# too many appcompatv7-X folders

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, android-sdk-tools, android-appcompat

i'm a new user in this great website. my question is: whenever i create a new project in eclipse with "SDK" target 3.0+ and with option of adding activity the eclipse adds the "appcompatV7-x" folder which annoying me especially with too many projects, if someone know a method to delete them all or at least keep one folder please post your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself, thank you guys

Step #1: must make sure that only one appcompatv7 folder exist in the workspace and no version is newer than it (i.e: appcompatv7-1) and if any delete them.

Step#2: Right_Click on each project and select (Properties - android ) and in Library section select the appcompatv7-x and delete it.

Step#3: click on "Add" and select the only one appcompatv7 you left in step#1 (make sure it not closed before you do this step)

Step#4: click on "Apply" then "Ok" and now you have only single appcompat folder for your projects and now its cleaner. 
when making new project delete it's included appcompat folder from workspace and from project properties then add your old folder. hope my answer help someone confused like i was :D

Comment: another important thing is to add the "android-support-v4" file which in "C:\Users\YourName\workspace\appcompat_v7\libs" folder to all projects "lib" folder to avoid
"Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies" which is annoying error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just getting started with Android, don't make your projects runnable over several versions of Android. These compatibility libraries are added automatically when you specify that you want to allow users of your app to be using old versions of Android.    If you really want to build a project that works with the older versions, then it's better that they get put there automatically than trying to figure out how to include them - but I don't think that's your main issue at this point.

Comment: yes i'm new to android development but i know about Support Libraries which adds automatically when creating a new project with a blank activity with SDK target +3.0
but i really need to know any method to hide them because i can't make all my existing projects from scratch again.

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Pick one of the `appcompat` directories. For the purposes of this answer, I will refer to this directory as `$FOO`.

Step #2: Right-click over one of your projects in the Eclipse Package Explorer and choose Properties. Click on the Android category. Scroll to the bottom of the Android details, to the list of attached library projects. If it is attached to an `appcompat` library project other than `$FOO`, delete the existing attachment and add an attachment to `$FOO`.

Step #3: Repeat Step #2 for all of your projects.

Step #4: Delete all `appcompat` projects other than `$FOO` from your workspace.

Step #5: In the future, rather than create a new project from the wizard, create a copy of an existing project that points to `$FOO` (e.g., Copy from the context menu for a project).